# Spring data JPA Repository @autowired gives null

Tags: spring, spring-data, autowired, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying out `spring-data-jpa`. With the help of [Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) and my prior spring knowledge, I've set up spring-data-jpa configuration but the `Repository` that I `@Autowired` is always returned null. I've refer to other questions over here but I haven't figure out the solution.

My **ApplicationContext** configuration is

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("devopsdistilled.operp.server.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("server/jdbc.properties")
@ComponentScan("devopsdistilled.operp.server.data")
public class JpaContext {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Value("devopsdistilled.operp.server.data.entity")
    private String packagesToScan;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        dataSource.setInitialSize(2);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter
                .setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        emf.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new HibernateJpaDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
                .getObject());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProps = new Properties();
        hibernateProps.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return hibernateProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

My **Entity** definition is as follows

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {
```

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7751126479626962944L;
private Long id;
private String name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new String("Id: " + getId() + "\nName: " + getName());
}
```

}

My **Repository** definition is as follows

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository {
}
```

While I try to run a sample application as follows

public class ServerApp {

```
@Inject
ItemRepository itemRepository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            JpaContext.class);
    new ServerApp().sampleMethod();
    System.out.println(context);
}

public void sampleMethod() {
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setName("Test Item");
    item = itemRepository.save(item);
    System.out.println(itemRepository.findOne(item.getId()));
    System.out.println("From sampleMethod");
}
```

}

I get the following output in console.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:24 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version 
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:24 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:24 PM org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:24 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:25 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect 
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:25 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:25 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version 
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:25 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists Item
Hibernate: create table Item (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Apr 29, 2013 5:31:25 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at devopsdistilled.operp.server.ServerApp.sampleMethod(ServerApp.java:27)
    at devopsdistilled.operp.server.ServerApp.main(ServerApp.java:20)
```

As it can be seen in output, there is `NullPointerException` and thus the `ItemRepository` is not `Autowired`.

I've written a **Test** for the Repository as follows.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JpaContext.class)
@Transactional
public class ItemRepositoryTest {
```

```
@Inject
private ItemRepository itemRepository;
private Item item;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    item = new Item();
    item.setName("Test Item");
}

@Test
public void testSave() {
    item = itemRepository.save(item);
    Assert.assertEquals(item, itemRepository.findOne(item.getId()));
}
```

}

**What is missing in my configuration?**

**How can I solve this problem?**

Thanks

Comment: do you have a test configuration that you are loading?  Or is it the same configuration for all pieces of the application>

Comment: It is same configuration.

Comment: I see.  Can you create a test configuration file as well?  It is beneficial in the long run to have one of these because your test environment will most likely persist to an in memory location and not a "real" database.  Also I think it will help us track down the underlying issue.

Comment: Actually I just started to write Test today, so very less knowledge.
I've been thinking to write separate configurations but I stick with one so that I get right with `spring-data-jpa` configuration first and then optimizing test environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is this line:

```
new ServerApp().sampleMethod();
```

When you invoke from a main you can still rely on autowiring, but you need to use the `ApplicationContext` to retrieve the bean.

Like this:

```
ServerApp app = context.getBean("ServerApp");
```

**Note** It is important to note this function is overloaded, so you may have better luck with the overload

When you use the `new` keyword you are bypassing Spring and utilizing pure Java instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after I define @Bean for `ServerApp` there is no errors.
But my real problem is when I write test for the Repository. I'll update my question.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect ok let me know when.

Comment: Any idea why in main method just '@Autowire' doesn't work? I struggled a lot with this. I had Null pointer Exception unless I use ApplicationContext to retrieve the bean.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to declare your repository using the JpaRepository generics [as explaneid in the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e1349)?

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

In my case it's not working without specifying the ID and the type of the entity. Hope this helps.

Additionally, if you want to initialize your repositories manually in your test, use something like this:

```
    @Before
    public void init() {
        JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);

        yourRepository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(YourRepository.class);
        assertNotNull(yourRepository);

        // In case your need to initialize a custom repository use this
        OtherRepositoryCustom otherRepoImpl = new OtherRepositoryImpl();
        otherRepository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(OtherRepository.class, otherRepoImpl);
        assertNotNull(otherRepository);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed that. Actually I had those generics but may be I messed up unknowingly removing the generics while copying while pasting here. Also when I remove those generics, Eclipse shows error.
Also, I don't know what I did, my application is working now. :-/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion regarding the test, but I'm not familiar about the advantage of testing such a way. Also, I'm starting TDD just today.

Comment: The only advantage is that any repository isn't initialized but the ones you manually declare in `@Before` method. This increases the speed of your test if you have so many repositories, because you're just initializing the ones you need.

Comment: Thank You :-) Is there any other tweaks you can provide to tweak my `ApplicationContext`. I've doubt its messed up some how.